# Jquery and html:: Getting the nearest data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a similar piece of code I am working on right now:

```
<div class="gallery-category">
    <h2 data-gallery="Exterior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Exterior
    </h2>
    <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
        <div class="gallery-image-tile">
            <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/content/image/image1.jpg">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-category">
    <h2 data-gallery="Interior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Interior
    </h2>
    <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
        <div class="gallery-image-tile">
            <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/content/image/image2.jpg">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to get the value `Exterior` if I click on the image `image1.jpg`. I created the data attribute `data-gallery` and was trying to get the value by using `$('[data-gallery]').data("gallery")` but getting only the first value.

What I need looks something like this :

**Clicking on `image1` getting the value 'Exterior'.**

**Clicking on `image2` getting the value 'Interior'.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could by attaching the click to the class `.gallery-img` then after the click use the `closest()` method to go up to parents `div` and find the `h2` element with `data-gallery` attribute  :

```
$('.gallery-img picture').on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('.gallery-category').find('h2[data-gallery]').data("gallery")
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.gallery-img picture').on('click',function(){
  var gallery_data = $(this).closest('.gallery-category').find('h2[data-gallery]').data("gallery");
  
  console.log(gallery_data);
})
```

```css
picture {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-category">
  <h2 data-gallery="Exterior">
    <span class="gallery-back"></span>
    Exterior
  </h2>
  <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-image-tile">
      <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="/content/image/image1.jpg">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-category">
  <h2 data-gallery="Interior">
    <span class="gallery-back"></span>
    Interior
  </h2>
  <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-image-tile">
      <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="/content/image/image2.jpg">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by placing a click event handler on the `picture` elements, then traversing the DOM using `closest()` to get the nearest `.gallery-category`, then `find()` to get the `h2`. Finally, `data()` will get you the value you require. Try this:

```js
$('picture').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).closest('.gallery-category').find('h2').data('gallery');
  console.log(text);
});
```

```css
picture {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-category">
  <h2 data-gallery="Exterior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Exterior
    </h2>
  <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-image-tile">
      <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="/content/image/image1.jpg">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-category">
  <h2 data-gallery="Interior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Interior
    </h2>
  <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
    <div class="gallery-image-tile">
      <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="/content/image/image2.jpg">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('picture').click(function() {
    // >> "Exterior"
    console.log($(this).closest('.gallery-category>h2').data('gallery')))
})
```

Explanation:

`$(this)` is the element that was clicked (i.e. the `picture`). So, from it we look up its parents until we find the `h2` which is a direct child of an element with `gallery-category` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('picture').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).closest('div.gallery-items-wrap').prev().data('gallery') );
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/322L2svv/)**

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just map the indexes of the gallery elements to the indexes of the pictures?

```js
var galleries = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gallery]');
var pics = document.getElementsByTagName('picture');

// Loop over the pictures
for(let i = 0; i < pics.length; ++i){
  // Set up a click event handler for each
  pics[i].addEventListener('click', function(){  
    // That grabs the corresponding index in the galleries
    console.log(galleries[i].getAttribute('data-gallery'));
  });
}
```

```css
picture {width:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-category">
    <h2 data-gallery="Exterior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Exterior
    </h2>
    <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
        <div class="gallery-image-tile">
            <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/content/image/image1.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.techinsights.com/uploadedImages/Public_Website/Content_-_Primary/Teardowncom/Sample_Reports/sample-icon.png" alt="MDN">
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-category">
    <h2 data-gallery="Interior">
        <span class="gallery-back"></span>
        Interior
    </h2>
    <div class="gallery-items-wrap">
        <div class="gallery-image-tile">
            <div class="gallery-img" data-analytics="photo-click">
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/content/image/image2.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.techinsights.com/uploadedImages/Public_Website/Content_-_Primary/Teardowncom/Sample_Reports/sample-icon.png" alt="MDN">                  
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```